# My app don´t show maps on my device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been looking for a solution in past 3 days and I can´t find a solution for my problem.
When I run my app on my device, using google maps api v2, show´s a message that I have to update google services. I follow every steps in google developers, and another tutorial and nothing. Here my code and the log cat... Please if anyone have a solution for this please help me.

Manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maps2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.example.maps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maps2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDJWkuzL3moJzGH4JcLJXQa9_q1vG7Q3Xc"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<fragment 
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = fm.getMap(); 

}
}
```

LogCat:

```
    11-04 16:13:21.921: E/Trace(27005): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-04 16:13:22.761: I/dalvikvm(27005): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method xg.b
11-04 16:13:22.761: W/dalvikvm(27005): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3765: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
11-04 16:13:22.761: D/dalvikvm(27005): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
11-04 16:13:22.761: I/dalvikvm(27005): Could not find method android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByTypeForPackage, referenced from method xg.c
11-04 16:13:22.761: W/dalvikvm(27005): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2421: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.getAccountsByTypeForPackage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account;
11-04 16:13:22.761: D/dalvikvm(27005): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
11-04 16:13:23.762: I/PeopleDatabaseHelper(27005): cleanUpNonGplusAccounts done.
11-04 16:13:24.253: D/dalvikvm(27005): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d82670
11-04 16:13:24.263: D/dalvikvm(27005): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d82670
11-04 16:13:24.263: D/dalvikvm(27005): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d82670, skipping init
11-04 16:13:24.263: D/Icing(27005): Init last flush num docs 159 last docstore size 41216
11-04 16:13:24.273: D/Icing(27005): Docid map file has data, scanning...
11-04 16:13:24.283: D/Icing(27005): Scanning /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.docids found 160 documents, last docstore location 41216
11-04 16:13:24.283: D/Icing(27005): File /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.perdocdata contains 160 records of size 6
11-04 16:13:24.323: D/Icing(27005): Corpus scoring data inited successfully num corpora 2
11-04 16:13:24.323: D/Icing(27005): Init docstore ok num docs 160 bytes 41472
11-04 16:13:25.434: V/Icing(27005): Lite index crc computed in 0.092ms
11-04 16:13:25.434: V/Icing(27005): Lite index init ok in 122.498ms
11-04 16:13:25.434: D/Icing(27005): Lite index recovered docid (158, 159]
11-04 16:13:25.434: V/Icing(27005): Warming lite-index took 0.031ms
11-04 16:13:25.434: V/Icing(27005): Warming lexicon took 0.122ms
11-04 16:13:25.434: V/Icing(27005): Warming display mappings took 0.031ms
11-04 16:13:25.434: D/Icing(27005): Init index ok num docs 160
11-04 16:13:25.434: D/Icing(27005): Init done
11-04 16:13:33.322: E/Trace(27293): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-04 16:13:33.582: D/PackageAddedReceiver(27293): package added com.example.maps2
11-04 16:13:34.633: I/dalvikvm(27293): Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method xg.b
11-04 16:13:34.633: W/dalvikvm(27293): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3765: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
11-04 16:13:34.633: D/dalvikvm(27293): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
11-04 16:13:34.743: I/dalvikvm(27293): Could not find method android.accounts.AccountManager.getAccountsByTypeForPackage, referenced from method xg.c
11-04 16:13:34.743: W/dalvikvm(27293): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 2421: Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;.getAccountsByTypeForPackage (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[Landroid/accounts/Account;
11-04 16:13:34.743: D/dalvikvm(27293): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
11-04 16:13:35.554: I/PeopleDatabaseHelper(27293): cleanUpNonGplusAccounts done.
11-04 16:13:36.565: D/dalvikvm(27293): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d851d8
11-04 16:13:36.965: D/dalvikvm(27293): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d851d8
11-04 16:13:36.965: D/dalvikvm(27293): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-1/libAppDataSearch.so 0x40d851d8, skipping init
11-04 16:13:36.965: D/Icing(27293): Init last flush num docs 159 last docstore size 41216
11-04 16:13:36.965: D/Icing(27293): Docid map file has data, scanning...
11-04 16:13:36.975: D/Icing(27293): Scanning /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.docids found 160 documents, last docstore location 41216
11-04 16:13:36.975: D/Icing(27293): File /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/AppDataSearch/main/cur/ds.perdocdata contains 160 records of size 6
11-04 16:13:37.025: D/Icing(27293): Corpus scoring data inited successfully num corpora 2
11-04 16:13:37.025: D/Icing(27293): Init docstore ok num docs 160 bytes 41472
11-04 16:13:37.596: I/Recovery(27293): Received: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be.recovery.AccountRecoveryBackgroundService$Receiver }
11-04 16:13:38.457: I/Recovery(27293): Received: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be.recovery.AccountRecoveryBackgroundService$Receiver }
11-04 16:13:38.717: V/Icing(27293): Lite index crc computed in 0.122ms
11-04 16:13:38.727: V/Icing(27293): Lite index init ok in 152.679ms
11-04 16:13:38.727: D/Icing(27293): Lite index recovered docid (158, 159]
11-04 16:13:38.727: V/Icing(27293): Warming lite-index took 0.031ms
11-04 16:13:38.737: V/Icing(27293): Warming lexicon took 6.592ms
11-04 16:13:38.747: V/Icing(27293): Warming display mappings took 7.050ms
11-04 16:13:38.747: D/Icing(27293): Init index ok num docs 160
11-04 16:13:38.747: D/Icing(27293): Init done
```

Please test the app on your devices and tell me if this message appears in your devices.

Comment: Did you try this on real device or emulator? If real device, is it running Android 2.2 (or above) and having Google Play Store installed? If emulator, is it running Android 4.2.2 with Google APIs? [Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: Google Services is handled by the Google Play app. The problem is there, not with your app. Make sure your Google Play app is up to date on your device. http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Comment: I use a real device, the target is 4.2.2, and I try in another device and appears the same message.

Answer (score 2):

See here,just change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and make sure that your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space only.

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.

Comment: If I run your code without this "<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />" give me a error and app don´t start. If I put this meta-data in manifest the app run but appears the same message on my device "this application will not run until you update the google play services". I'm frustrated with it

Comment: Have you created your own map API key with your sha-1 + package name which is mentioned at android manifest file by going to Google API console?

Comment: Yes I did, and I have update google play services too in sdk, I import google play services lib into my workspace, and add this libraries into my project...

Comment: Which code you placed at "<meta-data android:name=  "...etc. n Make sure that the lib project should be in same work space, and especially in sha1+package name make sure package name which is mentioned in android manifest file.

Comment: I found the solution for this... I had to clear the cache and data from google play store on my device. After this update the google play services on my device I my app worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling methods that are not available ? Your trace says "Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method xg.b".

We can see in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html#getApplicationRestrictions%28java.lang.String%29) that the method is available from API lvl 18, and since you're trying to run that on a 4.2.2 device (API level 17), this could be the reason of the crash ...

Comment: But I don't use that method in my project :s